# Enumerate Emberjs Data Relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do you enumerate a model's relationships in a template? I currently have two models: `user` and `role`.

### user.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email:    DS.attr('string'),
  roles:    DS.hasMany('role', { async: true }),
});
```

### role.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  users:       DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

The user is populating correctly when I visit `/user/foo` (the username is the ID). But I cannot get the role to show up correctly. When I use a naïve `{{user.roles}}` I get:

```
<(subclass of Ember.ArrayProxy):ember806>
```

The models for users and roles are all loading thanks to an RSVP, but I'd like to specifically enumerate the `name` attribute of the roles associated with the loaded user model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: Ember 2.7.0

Comment: Are you using `{{#each}}` in your template to display the roles?

Comment: I did try that and it just shows up blank. Specifically: `{{#each role in user.roles}}` and `{{#each user.roles as |role|}}`.

Comment: `{{#each user.roles as |role|}} {{role.name}} {{/each}}` should work.

Comment: Still not populated... If that's not it... Could if be how the data is loaded in initially? When returning the user object from the server I return the roles like this (xpath) `$.data.attributes.roles` where `roles` is an array.

Comment: You're missing the other side of the relationship in the 'role' model. That could be messing things up.